# Disable "Choose" button fileUpload in primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the fileLimit seted to 1. 
I want that when the user choose the first file, the choose button get disabled.

Comment: I want the the user dont TRY to upload more than 1 file.

Comment: Yes, it has. When the user try to upload the second file, it display the error message. But I dont want to the user can upload the second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved putting a disabled atribut in fileUpload liked with a boolean variable in my bean. 
When the file finish to upload, the variable change his values to true and I update the fileUpload componnt, then the component get disabled.
Thank you guys to the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

xhtml

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" 
              mode="advanced" 
              dragDropSupport="false" 
              update="messages,@this" 
              sizeLimit="100000" 
              fileLimit="1" 
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
              disabled="#{fileUploadView.fileUploadCount >= 1}"/>

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
```

managedbean

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    private int fileUploadCount;

    public int getFileUploadCount() {
        return fileUploadCount;
    }

    public void setFileUploadCount(int fileUploadCount) {
        this.fileUploadCount = fileUploadCount;
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        fileUploadCount = fileUploadCount + 1;
    }
}
```

This proposed is easy to change file limit. When you want to change fileLimit to 2 you just change
`fileLimit="2"` and `disabled="#{fileUploadView.fileUploadCount >= 2}"` without modify managedbean.